# Source Han problems with vertical typesetting

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts

In Microsoft Word 2010, I’m trying to typeset vertical CJK texts. However, when I use Source Han Serif in its original (Japanese) recension, it only turns the glyphs sidewise. What could the matter be?

Comment: Example: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/dnHkgDW

Comment: Which version of [Source Han Serif](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/releases) do you use? Please give a screenshot of what you see when you type the same glyphs as in your above example.

Comment: My Source Han Serif is the current 1.001 version, and Source Han Sans is in 2.0. MS Word is 2010. Additional data: reinstalling Source keeps the error, but installing them in their repacked Google identitly, as ‘Noto’, works properly.

Comment: Examples: typing in SHSerif-JP, in SHSerif-K, in SHSerif-K in Hangul, in Noto CJK Serif Korean, which is supposed to be same as 2.

https://imgur.com/jHtB3jC

Comment: The documentation mentions both vertical and horizontal characters. Look for such an option maybe named vert or vrt. Text: "The usual and expected set of vertical glyphs is included, some of which are region- or language-specific. In addition, all glyphs for kana, meaning not only those for small kana, include a vertical glyph variant. A small number of vertical glyphs happen to be encoded for compatibility reasons, most of which can be found in the U+FExx range, but they are still accessible via the 'vert' GSUB feature as vertical variants of the horizontal forms that are encoded elsewhere".

Answer (score 0):

I don't use or know Japanese, but it seems that your problem with the direction of
the text is related to a strange limitation in Word.

I quote from the article
[Changing Text Orientation](https://word.tips.net/T001707_Changing_Text_Orientation.html):

> Word provides you with the capability of changing the orientation of
>   your text, provided that the text is within an AutoShape, text box, or
>   table cell. This means that you can rotate this type of text ninety
>   degrees, in either direction, from its normal appearance. To change
>   text orientation, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Select the AutoShape, text box, or table cell that contains the text whose orientation you want to change.
> 2. Choose the Text Direction option from the Format menu. Word displays the Text Direction dialog box. (See Figure 1.)
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Choose an orientation from those offered.
> 4. Click on OK.

The solution might be to write the text inside a table or a text box so
that its orientation can be changed to vertical.

Comment: @AlexanderZ.: Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY6Po8C_3t0) (not by me) shows how to do it. Basically, you need to ensure that you’ve added your vertical language (Japanese, in this case) as an allowed text language in Word - from the Start Menu, select Programs/Microsoft Office/Microsoft Office 2010 Tools/Microsoft Office 2010 Language Preferences, then **Add** Japanese as an Additional Editing Language.

Once you’ve done this, when you go into Word, you can select the Page Layout tab, where you should now see a Text Direction button, which will allow you to select vertical or horizontal.

(*This should work for Word 2013 and 2016 as well., though the tab name changes to just ‘Layout’*)